# Given 2d array of 0s and 1s, find all the squares in it using backtracking

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, backtracking

in this 2d array 1 represents a point and 0 represents blank area.
for example this array:

```
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

my answer should be 2, because there are 2 squares (or rectangles) in this array like this

### [image: like this]

all the points should be used, and you can't make another square | rectangle if all its points are already used (like we can't make another square from the point in the middle to the point in the top right) because they are both already used in other squares, you can use any point multiple times just if at least one corner is not used point.
I could solve it as an implementation problem, but I am not understanding how backtracking is related to this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your #1 is wrong.  It spans 3x2 which is not a square.

Comment: Sorry, squares or rectangles.

Comment: Aren't there 4? (0|0) to (2|1), (0|0) to (4|3), (4|0) to (2|1) and (2|1) to (4|3)

Comment: No, because they both are used already, so you can't use (used point) with another used one.

Comment: You really need to detail what your requirements are then.  So far you have missed to critical pieces of information.

Comment: I think that's because I don't need a solution for it because I already solved it (implementation), my question is how backtracking is related to this problem

Comment: Not sure what you mean by they both are already used, then your answer is still wrong because 0,0 to 2,1 and 0,0 to 4,0 is using an already used point, 0,0 was used in the first instance.

Comment: Ahh i see the "You can use any point multiple times just if at lease one corner is not used." edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking, lets take a look at another possible answer to your problem, you listed:

- {0,0} to (2,1}
- {0,0} to {4,0}

As one solution another solution is (With respect to the point can be used multiple times as long as one point is unused):

- {4,0} to {2,1} (first time 4,0 and 2,1 is used)
- {0,0} to {2,1} (first time 0,0 is used)
- {0,0} to {4,4} (first time 4,4 is used)

Which is 3 moves, with backtracking it is designed to show you alternative results using recursion.  In this equation if you start the starting location for calculating the squares at different areas of the array you can achieve different results.

for an example iterating starts from 0,0, and going right across each row trying to find all possible rectangles starting with [0,0] will give the solution you provided, iteratings starting from 4,0 and going left across each row trying to find all possible solutions will give my result.